Array Modifier Constant Offset (x) changes when I render
I've created an array of 7 planes with a constant offset of 1.5 inches. When I render with the F12 button, the offset changes so that objects are in the wrong position. Is there a workaround?


Edit: Here is the file. 
I can reproduce it on my machine (Ubuntu 22.04) by loading the file, editing the array (7 gray tiles) and hitting F12. The rendered array offset changes. :(

Hello and welcome to BSE. Can you share the blend file? https://blend-exchange.com

Hi, smorgan.. welcome.. a quick share as suggested will help clear this up more quickly

I've updated the post and added the .blend file. Since then, I've removed the array and replaced it with an array of cubes. Works correctly now.

You've keyframed the Distance value of your Array modifier, so I guess your problem is that you're trying to change this value but it always comes back to this value when you render. To fix your problem, simply remove the keyframe (to do that you can put your timeline player on the frame where the keyframe has been created, select it and press X):


Thanks, moonboots! I must have setup a keyframe inadvertently. I've never used keyframes. I learned something today. :)
